# To Plot a x-y graph in c# in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graph

Using two parameters to plot a line graph in C# using Visual Studio ( Using GUI).

Answer (score 2):

I would use the free MS Chart Controls.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Answer (score 1):

Check out ZedGraph (http://zedgraph.org). Open source, licensed under the LGPL.